# Python cap slice negative bound at list ends

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print a part of the list cut out of its middle

```
def region_around(lst, index):
    return lst[index-3:index+3]

lst = [i for i in range(10)]
print(region_around(lst, 5)) # correctly prints [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

print(region_around(lst, 0)) # incorrectly prints []
```

In the second case, `region_around(lst, 0)`, I want `[0, 1, 2]` as if the slice had been made with only the positive part `lst[:3]`

How can I constrain a slice like I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remembered the terminology was "clamp" and looking it up showed me that of course I can just do

```
def region_around(lst, index):
    return lst[max(0, index-3):index+3]
```

Comment: i was too fast ,nice